# Delineated/engraved lines on water (rivers, seas, lakes) - not isobates

Tags: qgis

I'm looking for method to accentuate the rivers' flow or reservoirs shape with delineated (engraving-like) lines. It is a technique commonly used on old, hand-drawn maps. I attach three screenshots as illustration.

I'm using QGIS 3.28.3.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

[image: example 3]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try some geometry generator expression like this. It will negative buffer by -3, -6, -9, -12 and create a randomized wave for each buffer:

```
collect_geometries( 
array_foreach(generate_series(-3,-12,-3),
wave_randomized( 
    geometry:=boundary(buffer( $geometry, @element)), 
    min_wavelength:=10, 
    max_wavelength:=50,
    min_amplitude:=0,
    max_amplitude:=1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [QGIS style Hub](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/?order_by=-upload_date&&is_gallery=true) Or at the [QGIS Resource Sharing plugin](https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/) both are great ressource for getting symbol or premade style.

For your specific case [Exponential Coastline Buffers](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/81/) or [Halftone Coastline](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/80/) (both style from Klas Karlsson) will probably fit your use case, if not these could be altered or mixed with other style to better suit you.